# Encrypt backups

Tags: macos, time-machine, disk-utility, encryption

Is it better to encrypt the hard drive you will use for Time Machine backup with Disk Utility or with Time Machine itself? I have noticed the the dialogue is slightly different, wherein Disk Utility a hint is not required, but with Time Machine it is... are there any other differences under the hood?

Comment: See this older question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/94930/22003 .

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is to try it yourself. From what I can recall, though, using the encryption option of Time Machine makes an encrypted [sparse bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_image) (a file) on an unencrypted disk, whereas the Disk Utility approach encrypts the entire disk.

Both methods are pretty rock solid (especially for the needs of insignificant consumers), so pick whichever seems more useful.